# Calculate subnet from IP Address and Mask using mysql query

Tags: mysql, ip-address

Is it possible to calculate the subnet if I have a IP address and mask using MySQL? I know to do this in PHP, but I am looking for a way to do this in MySQL.

For example, given the IP address 10.196.73.249/29 I'd like to return the network address of 10.196.73.248.

Comment: not a duplicate. I am not looking for cidr value of subnet, I am looking for subnet of ip address

Comment: ok, sorry, removed flag

Comment: Use [`INET_ATON()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html) to convert the IP to long. Then you should know how to do it the same way as in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already know how to do this in PHP, then the math shouldn't be much of a surprise for you, just IP address AND subnet mask.

Use MySQL's [`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) function to get the IP address into a number; this is equivalent to PHP's [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) function. To create the mask, use the [`REPEAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_repeat) function to put the requisite number of ones, and also to fill the rest of the string with zeroes. [`CONV()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) changes that binary string to decimal so we can do the math, and then a final [`INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) to get it back to IP address form.

```sql
SET @IP='10.196.73.249';
SET @CIDR='29';
SELECT CONV(CONCAT(REPEAT(1, @CIDR), REPEAT(0, 32 - @CIDR)), 2, 10) INTO @MASK;
SELECT @IP AS ip,
    INET_NTOA(@MASK) AS mask,
    INET_NTOA(INET_ATON(@IP) & @MASK) AS network;
```

Here is how to implement as a stored program:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_network (ipadd VARCHAR(15), mask VARCHAR(2)) RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
RETURN INET_NTOA(
    INET_ATON(ipadd) &
    CONV(CONCAT(REPEAT(1, mask), REPEAT(0, 32 - mask)), 2, 10)
);
```

This can be called like so:

```
root@localhost [test]> SELECT get_network("192.168.242.234", "20");
+--------------------------------------+
| get_network("192.168.242.234", "20") |
+--------------------------------------+
| 192.168.240.0                        |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: wow, that's perfect. that's a little program in mysql. only used to writing queries :)

Comment: I just threw the variables in to make it easier to read. If this is something you're going to be using a lot it might make more sense to save it as a stored procedure, which is actually a program in MySQL.

Comment: yes, it does make it very easy to read. Yes, I would be using this a lot and will save it as a stored procedure. I wanted to do it using mysql as it will be quicker than php loop

Comment: Thanks, was only reading on dev.mysql on how to do this. Makes it much easier. Just one question, what does 32- cidr do?

Comment: The first `REPEAT()` does the 1s, the second does the 0s.